# What is indexed requested status means when you fetch and render as google?

Tags: google-search-console

When I fetch and render my new url to Google webmaster tools, the status has "completed Indexed Requested", what does it means? Means has fetch and render OR google just check it and will fetch and render after that.

Answer (score 0):

"completed" is about Fetch and "index requested" is an other thing.
**Status:completed** means Webmaster tools could fetched truly 
**index requested** means you wanted to index the URL